# Stored Procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server so I have some basic questions about stored procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT( 
    shipment_id varchar2,
    item_no varchar2,
    quantity number,
    @total_weight int out)
as
BEGIN
     insert into test_new_shipment_weight
     values(1,100);
END ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT;
```

1. Why does it give errors when I try to put `@` before the input parameters?
2. I get error

   > Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting....."?
3. For this:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT( 
     shipment_id varchar2,
     item_no varchar2,
     quantity number)
   as
      declare total_weight int  -->error:"Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:......"
   BEGIN
        insert into test_new_shipment_weight
        values(1,100);
   END ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT;
   ```

   I tried to put `@` before `total_weight` but that doesn't help. I have looked through variable declaration and parameters online but those syntax aren't working either.

Comment: Because your syntax is incorrect. Parameter definitions are not surrounded with brackets. There should be nothing after the final `END`. All parameters need to start with `@`. Use `OUTPUT` not `out` . Also your insert statement should list the columns in the table you are inserting into

Comment: And SQL Server doesn't have `CREATE OR REPLACE` - either `CREATE PROCEDURE`, or then `ALTER PROCEDURE`

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of @total_weight inside the BEGIN..END block

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT 

  @shipment_id varchar2,
  @item_no varchar2,
  @quantity number

as   
BEGIN
   declare @total_weight int
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't do CREATE OR REPLACE in sql server when creating a stored procedure, that's why you are getting the error. Here what you need to create the procedure.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE ADD_TOTAL_WEIGHT(

@shipment_id varchar2,

@item_no varchar2,

@quantity number,

@total_weight int output)

as

BEGIN

insert into test_new_shipment_weight (columnname1, columnname2)

values(@item_no,@quantity);

END
```